# R Plotly legend filtering

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, plotly

I have copypasted the code example from plotly website (https://plot.ly/ggplot2/geom_bar), but the graph behave differently from the example when filtered; how can I have mine to be able to reshape like that?

code:

```
library(plotly)

DF <- read.table(text="Rank F1     F2     F3
1    500    250    50
2    400    100    30
3    300    155    100
4    200    90     10", header=TRUE)

library(reshape2)
DF1 <- melt(DF, id.var="Rank")

p <- ggplot(DF1, aes(x = Rank, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

p <- ggplotly(p)
```

From the web:
[image: Plotly website]

My RStudio Viewer:

[image: R Studio Viewer]

Comment: What do you mean by filtering.

Comment: variable `F2` is excluded on the plot, filtered by clicking the legend

Comment: Edit your question along with the code you used

Comment: Here there is no legend filtering!

Comment: @RUser okay, maybe I'm using a wrong phrase, it's filtered by directly clicking the legend, so it's not written on the code (if it's that you want). Plotly produces an interactive plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compare the data produced by the example code and the published code closely, you can see two differences.

1. The "wrong" graph has `base` values
2. The order is reversed between the two graphs

In order to prevent stacked bar graphs from not collapsing if you toggle a trace, you would need to erase the `base` values (and for aesthetic reasons reverse the order of the traces).

```
library(plotly)

DF <- read.table(text="Rank F1     F2     F3
1    500    250    50
2    400    100    30
3    300    155    100
4    200    90     10", header=TRUE)

library(reshape2)
DF1 <- melt(DF, id.var="Rank")

gp <- ggplot(DF1, aes(x = Rank, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

p <- ggplotly(gp)

for (i in 1:length(p$x$data)) {
  p$x$data[[i]]$base <- c()
  tmp <- p$x$data[[i]]
  p$x$data[[i]] <- p$x$data[[length(p$x$data) - i + 1]]
  p$x$data[[length(p$x$data) - i + 1]] <- tmp
}
p
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Would you know how to resize the yaxis too when we are filtering? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979194/ggplotly-stacked-bar-chart-not-resizing-after-filtering