# ggplotly stacked bar chart not resizing after filtering

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

For some reason when producing a plotly graph with the `ggplotly` function, the filtering does not seem to resize the y-axis. The filtered portion are simply removed, while yaxis stays at it's original length. Please see this example:

```r
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

lab <- paste("Vertical Label", c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

ds <- data.frame(x = sample(lab, size = 1000, replace = T),
                 y = sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = 1000, replace = T)) %>%
      group_by(x,y) %>% summarise(count= n())

ggplotly(
ggplot(ds, aes(x = x,y=count, fill = y)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) 
)
```

[image]

Same approach with `plot_ly` function works. However, I needed similar results with `ggploty`

```r
plot_ly(ds, x = ~x, y = ~count, type = 'bar', color = ~y
        ) %>% layout(title = "Vertical Axis Lables",
                      xaxis = list(title = ""),
                      yaxis = list(title = ""), barmode = 'stack')
```

[image]

I couldn't find anything helpful in stack overflow or google. Just came across an incomplete answer here:
https://community.rstudio.com/t/ggplotly-bar-chart-not-resizing-after-filtering/115675/3

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying a tip from [R Plotly Legend Filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44713197/r-plotly-legend-filtering) enables re-stacking and similar ordering, while enabling auto-scaling provides y-axis adaptation:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

lab <- paste("Vertical Label", c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

ds <- data.frame(x = sample(lab, size = 1000, replace = T),
             y = sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = 1000, replace = T)) %>%
             group_by(x,y) %>% summarise(count= n())

p <- ggplotly(
  ggplot(ds, aes(x = x,y=count, fill = y)) +
    geom_col() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) 
)
for (i in 1:length(p$x$data)) {
  p$x$data[[i]]$base <- c()
  tmp <- p$x$data[[i]]
  p$x$data[[i]] <- p$x$data[[length(p$x$data) - i + 1]]
  p$x$data[[length(p$x$data) - i + 1]] <- tmp
}
p
```

[image: Filtered plot]

Comment: Wow, how did I not come across that post, Thank you for sharing and appreciate your answer!

Comment: It's a bummer that y axis doesn't resize as well. Oh well, gotta lose something.

Comment: The y-axis does resize for me if the plotly control for auto-scale in the top-right-hand corner is enabled.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (I was locked out from my account). Appreciate the clarification from you :)

Answer (score 1):

It is only necessary to reset the base of the plotly variable for each of the x-axis elements that will be plotted.

```
for (i in 1:length(p$x$data)) {
  p$x$data[[i]]$base <- c()
}
```

In the above example, if you reset the order, (1) D does not resize and (2) purple overlays A (A is never seen unless purple is filtered).